# Multiple JREs in Linux system

Tags: linux, java, environment

In all the tutorials "how to install Oracle Java in Linux" it's said that OpenJDK **must** be purged from system. Is that absolutely necessary?

Is there any way to avoid conflicts between JREs/JDKs from different vendors (e.g. Oracle JDK and OpenJDK) on Linux systems (Linux Mint/Ubuntu in particular)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I don't remember doing it when I installed Oracle JDK 7, this is what I did (based on [this](http://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage)) for my Debian system (Mint/Ubuntu will do fine as well):

```
apt-get install java-package //it's in contrib
wget -c http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u21-b11/jre-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz
make-jpkg jre-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz
dpkg -i the-generated-package.deb
```

After that, the system will most likely keep OpenJDK as default, if you want to change that, run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and then select the proper JRE.

Answer (score 2):

In Debian and Ubuntu (possibly Mint too) there is a package `java-common` that has a tool  `update-java-alternatives` that does configure all Java alternatives with manuals at once.

It allows switching between many Java installations including OpenJDK and Oracle very easily.

For Ubuntu (and possibly Mint) I recommend using [Webupd8 packages](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) and installing `oracle-java7-set-default` along `oracle-java7-installer`. This will set appropriate environment variables (through `/etc/profile.d/jdk.*` scripts).

This way you can have many JDKs, switch between them and choose one default.

Answer (score 0):

You can install any number of JREs/JDKs, as long as you know which one you are using.